# How can i install dlib in my windows when i have also downloaded visual studio ?? This error starts comming

Tags: python, dlib

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.805]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\91935>pip install dlib
Collecting dlib
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1e/62/aacb236d21fbd08148b1d517d58a9d80ea31bdcd386d26f21f8b23b1eb28/dlib-19.18.0.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: dlib
    Running setup.py install for dlib ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\91935\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\91935\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-87kzpe74\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\91935\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-87kzpe74\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\91935\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-wqn_kh20\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: C:\Users\91935\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-87kzpe74\dlib\
    Complete output (80 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    package init file 'dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    running build_ext
    Building extension for Python 3.8.0 (tags/v3.8.0:fa919fd, Oct 14 2019, 19:21:23) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)]
    Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\91935\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-87kzpe74\dlib\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\91935\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-87kzpe74\dlib\build\lib.win32-3.8 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\users\91935\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\91935\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-87kzpe74\dlib\build\lib.win32-3.8'
    -- Building for: NMake Makefiles
    -- The C compiler identification is unknown
    -- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
    CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
      The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:

        cl

      is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

      To use the NMake generator with Visual C++, cmake must be run from a shell
      that can use the compiler cl from the command line.  This environment is
      unable to invoke the cl compiler.  To fix this problem, run cmake from the
      Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat).

      Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
      variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
      the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


    CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
      The CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:

        cl

      is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

      To use the NMake generator with Visual C++, cmake must be run from a shell
      that can use the compiler cl from the command line.  This environment is
      unable to invoke the cl compiler.  To fix this problem, run cmake from the
      Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat).

      Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
      variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
      to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    See also "C:/Users/91935/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-87kzpe74/dlib/build/temp.win32-3.8/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
    See also "C:/Users/91935/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-87kzpe74/dlib/build/temp.win32-3.8/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\91935\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-87kzpe74\dlib\setup.py", line 223, in <module>
        setup(
      File "c:\users\91935\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "c:\users\91935\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\users\91935\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\users\91935\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\91935\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "c:\users\91935\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "c:\users\91935\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\91935\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\91935\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "c:\users\91935\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\91935\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\91935\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-87kzpe74\dlib\setup.py", line 135, in run
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "C:\Users\91935\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-87kzpe74\dlib\setup.py", line 172, in build_extension
        subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
      File "c:\users\91935\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\91935\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-87kzpe74\\dlib\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\91935\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-87kzpe74\\dlib\\build\\lib.win32-3.8', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\\users\\91935\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\91935\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-87kzpe74\\dlib\\build\\lib.win32-3.8']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\91935\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\91935\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-87kzpe74\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\91935\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-87kzpe74\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\91935\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-wqn_kh20\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.

C:\Users\91935>
```

Comment: Can you examine your post and see if you can't improve its content.  It looks very poor to the point where it can't be followed.

Comment: you forgot to describe problem in question. Title is not place for this. Downvote.

Answer (score 2):

For that you need to install all the dependencies along with visual studio like **Cmake** and all.

Let me share the proper document for installation

> https://www.learnopencv.com/install-dlib-on-windows/

Answer (score 0):

This link can be helpful: [how to install Dlib library](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HqjcqpCNiZg)

For me the best way is to install Python 3.6 and do like he does. (had many problems already)